# In linux how to set Python so that when using python it will use python3 and not python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonpath

When I type python --version it gives python --version I would like the default behaviour to use python3. I do not what to have to type "python3" each time I create to run python. In linux hwo would I change this?

Comment: Do you need this to work for programs with shebang lines? That is, should a script that has the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python` actually run Python 3? Is there a reason it's such a problem to just type the `3`?

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.bash_profile`, add the following:

```
export PATH=/Users/reblochonmasque/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/:$PATH
alias python3=/Users/reblochonmasque/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/python
alias python=/Users/reblochonmasque/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/python

export PATH=/Users/reblochonmasque/anaconda3/envs/py2k/bin/:$PATH
alias python2=/Users/reblochonmasque/anaconda3/envs/py2k/bin/python
```

Replace the `PATH` with the path to the python installation on your system; that will be something like this

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

The alias allows you to launch python3 with either `python`, or `python3`, and python2 with `python2` at the command line